# Is PPR pipe that is twisted around its axis still reliable?

Tags: pipe

A PPR pipe is twisted (not bent) around its central axis by the weight of flexible pipes (and water in them) that is connected to its exit which is right angle to the pipe (that is the reason for the twisting force).

All the pipes are mounted to wall (not buried in wall or there won't be such problems). The mounts only keep the pipe from move, but cannot prevent the twisting since the pipe can twist in each mount (and bend a little since there is ~0.x meter space between mounts).

Not sure whether the twisting will produce large shear stress inside the pipe and will it be reliable anymore?

Are there good ideas to balance the twisting force?

Note: the pipe under discussion is not bent since there is no force to bend it, but the pipe that is right angle to the twisted pipe is bent a little since the twisting force acts like a bending force on this second pipe which is not under discussion here.

Comment: picture please!

Comment: Why are you twisting these pipes?  Are you trying to make them fail?

Comment: Why can you not properly support the connected pipes? Please post a photo of the situation.

Comment: Replace the flexible plumbing with rigid plumbing, properly mounted to the... whatever it's mounted to... and that should prevent twisting. But, more importantly, pictures, since we're having a difficult time understanding what you're describing